# How to get default gateway with a dhcp

Tags: dhcp, gateway

I have ubuntu 12.04 and I have configured /etc/network/interfaces like this

```
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet dhcp
```

I also have

```
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 60.60.60.1 
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 60.60.60.0
        broadcast 60.60.60.255
```

and eth0 is similarly configured.

When I do sudo route I don't see default gw.
I just see `60.60.60.0 * 255.255.255.0 eth1`
and similarly

```
10.0.0.0  *   255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth2
```

Since the default gw is not present, I have got a proper 10.x.x.x IP address but no way to connect outside . How do I get the default gw automatically setup.
I can add it using route add default gw and that works. But when I move locations, then I will have to keep on setting route add at every place manually

Comment: Look at `/var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.eth2.leases`, check that there's an `option routers` setting there. This is what the dhclient received from the DHCP server. If there's no `option routers`, it means the DHCP server is not sending the default gateway or router setting.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer from this link https://serverfault.com/questions/527383/change-default-route-to-dhcp-interface-without-a-route-push
I essentially set "post-up route del default dev eth2" and for any other interface on which I did not want the default gw (these were all addresses with static configuration).
after doing /etc/init.d/networking restart , ubuntu will automatically pick up the default gw to the dhcp server and that worked. It took me 3+ hours of searching to find this :-)

Answer (score 1):

Basically dhclient appears to only set the default gateway when routers are provided by the server and when a current default gateway is not set. so, as doon mentioned, you can add a "route del default gw" to your network configuration or you can do this manually (or in your own script) before dhclient is called.